# Code for creating sockets in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to create a server and client network using three computers inside my LAN. I have read the following [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to create a server-client communication. I am wondering what those lines of code perform in the below example:

```
// Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
// The DNS name of the computer
// running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
Socket listener = new  
Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
```

I am not familiar with network stuff. I do not understanding if those lines create a socket with specific IP and port which is waiting a response from clients. Is there a correspondent example for client socket?

**EDIT:** I have the following setup. Three computers with three kinect 2 which run a c# project which capture the kinect stream and stores it to the hard disk. I want when in the server is pressed record to simultanesouly record the stream from all kinects.

**EDIT2:** I am trying to run the client version and I am receiving the following error:

[image]

Comment: The socket you make here does not yet listen, you only created an object that CAN.

Comment: I think the topic of networking is to complex to code without good background knowledge. Would suggest to start there and dive into the basics. Or explain what and why you want to it - maybe there is already a solution.

Comment: I wanted to give a signal from server to clients. I have a project which save kinect streams. I want to do to so from different pc with different kinect. When I am pressing record in the server in the same time to store the streams both from server and clients. I have a project which stores streams and i want to run it in the same time both from the server and from the clients.

Comment: Agree with @silverfighter, this is a complicated subject. Start with a basic client and server side and get that to work. When you understand what is happening there, try to extend your program to what you really want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link you posted there is also an [Asynchronous Client Socket example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx). Is that not what you are looking for?

```
// Connect to a remote device.
try {
    // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
    // The name of the 
    // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Connect to the remote endpoint.
    client.BeginConnect( remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
    connectDone.WaitOne();

    // Send test data to the remote device.
    Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");
    sendDone.WaitOne();

    // Receive the response from the remote device.
    Receive(client);
    receiveDone.WaitOne();

    // Write the response to the console.
    Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

    // Release the socket.
    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    client.Close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10555424)

Comment: It does answer the original question